# Codigo funciona com uma messagebox mas sem não?

Tags: c#, winforms, switch, radiobutton

Boa tarde, estou a fazer um pequeno trabalho escolar para aprender a controlar radio buttons com um switch em winforms

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        Thread th = new Thread(() =>
        {

            while (true)
            {
                RadioButton btn = this.tabPage1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(x => x.Checked).FirstOrDefault();


                if (btn != null && btn.Checked)
                {
                    switch (btn.Name)
                    {
                        case "radioButton1":
                            MessageBox.Show("Ronaldo");
                            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                            lblNome1.Visible = true;
                            lblPos1.Visible = true;
                            break;

                        case "radioButton2":
                            MessageBox.Show("Messi");
                            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                            lblNome2.Visible = true;
                            lblPos2.Visible = true;
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        th.Start();




    }
```

Não tem erros de syntax apenas os visibles so são ativados se houver uma messagebox porem esta como esta dentro de um ciclo de reptição infinito, irá estar sempre a aparecer e para meu conhecimento não tem como a parar

Agradeço o tempo a quem me conseguir ajudar a resolver este problema ou a quem tentou.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de utilizar uma Thread com loop infinito para essas validações?

Comment: Para não ter que estar a clicar em um botão para realizar a ação do switch, é o unico metodo que conheco até agora para o codigo estar sempre a correr como se fosse live

Comment: Além do que o @PedroPaulo já disse, tem certeza que precisa do `switch` isto também provavelmente é um erro. Parece estar querendo usar todas ferramentas possíveis, mesmo que elas sejam inadequadas. Quase todo uso de `thread` que eu vi está errado, é improvável que seu caso esteja certo. Dica, só use o que domina, se não domina, não use, ou domine antes de usar.

Comment: O exercicio foi dado pelo meu professor, controlar rdb com um switch, eu so juntei a thread para não ter que clicar em um botão, eu nem sei usar threads, verdade, mas foi assim que vi online, e não, não domino c# mas gostava de dominar e por isso estou aprendendo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O WinForms baseia-se em *rapid application development* e muitas operações em interface gráfica estão relacionadas aos eventos que ocorrem na interface.

Como exemplo, "amarrei" abaixo o efeito do evento de clicar no radio button a um manipulador de eventos chamado `RadioClicado(object, System.EventArgs)`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Amarração do evento de clique dos radio buttons ao manipulador.
    radioButton1.Click += RadioClicado;
    radioButton2.Click += RadioClicado;
}

// Manipulador de evento de clique em radio button.
public void RadioClicado(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is RadioButton)
    {
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
        switch (rb.Name)
        {
            case "radioButton1":
                //MessageBox.Show("Ronaldo");
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                lblNome1.Visible = true;
                lblPos1.Visible = true;
                break;

            case "radioButton2":
                //MessageBox.Show("Messi");
                pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                lblNome2.Visible = true;
                lblPos2.Visible = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Normalmente, as operações em interface gráfica devem ocorrer na *thread* própria da interface. Talvez por isso a *thread* que você abre para verificar o estado do radio button esteja provocando condição de corrida (*race condition*), e o uso de um MessageBox mitiga essa condição com a inclusão de uma pausa na *thread* concorrente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, realmente resultou e é verdade, eu pesquisei mais e estava sim numa race condition, muito obrigado por seu tempo